# disable full screen for neo4j-desktop-1.3.11-x86_64.AppImage

Tags: neo4j, desktop

when I start neo4j from neo4j-desktop-1.3.11-x86_64.AppImage,
it starts in full screen.  I then have to go to Neo4j Browser
(Graph Apps) to File->Quit to exit.

I'd like to start the Neo4j Desktop 1.3.11 in normal mode.
What should I do so that the desktop does not take the full
screen.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get to File->Quit in full screen, are you sure?  Maybe you maximized the window?

Use F11 to switch in and out of full screen mode.

Expanding the window to fill the entire screen is different, and controlled by resizing the window or using the maximize icon in the top right of the window frame.

For me on Ubuntu 20.02 it appears Neo4j remembers the window size/location each time I quit, so when you launch it again it restores to that size/location.

Try F11 and/or manually resizing the window as required, then exit the app, fingers crossed the window will open to the size and location you last moved it to.